# Eliminate the parameter and images

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given $h : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ $$h(u,v) = (u^2 - v^2, 2uv)$$

where $A = \{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < u < \infty,-\infty < v < \infty \} $. What is the set $h(A)$?

Here is what I did:

Let $x=u^2 - v^2$ and $y = 2uv$, square and add, i.e.

$x^2 + y^2 = (u^2 -v^2)^2+4u^2v^2= u^4 + v^4 -2u^2v^2+4u^2v^2 = u^4 + v^4 + 2u^2v^2 = (u^2 + v^2)^2$

It would seem to suggest I am getting a circle, but with a hole because of $u \neq 0$

Comment: See what happens to a vertical line, $u = u_0$ fixed, vary $v.$

Comment: Try $u=1,$ vary $v.$

Comment: It's not a circle, since $x^2 + y^2$ is not constant. But, it could be regarded as an infinite family of circles.

Comment: If you let $z = u^2 + v^2$, then you have shown that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, which is a cone. Squish this cone down onto the $xy$ plane.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't $u^2 + v^2$ a constant? For every choice of $u,v$ I get a number.

Comment: @WillJagy, at $u = 1$, I get $x^2 + y^2 = (1 + v^2)^2$. I don't see how that my answer

Comment: @bubba, how are you getting a cone? We are in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @sizz -- I temporarily added a z-coordinate because then the equations produce something recognizable. As I said, you have to remove the z (squish the cone down onto the xy plane) to get the final answer.

Comment: Is $u^2 + v^2$ a constant? Well, for fixed values of $u$ and $v$ it is, of course. So, if $u$ and $v$ are fixed, you get a circle of radius $u^2 + v^2$. But, for different values of $u$ and $v$, you get different circles. That's what I meant by "an infinite family of circles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given map $h$ is the composition of two maps:

$$g(u,v) = (u^2 - v^2, 2 u v, u^2 + v^2)$$

and

$$p(x,y,z) = (x, y, 0)$$

The first of these, $g$, can be implicitized to give $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, which means that the range of this mapping lies on a cone whose axis runs in the $z$ direction. Here's a picture of a portion of this cone:

[image: cone2]

The range of the mapping $g$ does not cover the entire cone. Points $(x,0)$ with $x \le 0$ are excluded for reasons explained in my other answer. This is indicated by the (artificially enlarged) crack in the cone.

The second map, $p$ just projects this cone down onto the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Have you ever considered editing your previous answer and add this one there? Also, I don't really the reason why you make things complicated by introducing 3-dimensional maps.

Comment: Yes, I considered merging. But the two solutions seemed quite different, to me, so I decided to keep them separate. I introduced 3D because I immediately recognized the cone equation, and I thought that helped. Actually, for me, the 3D image is much clearer than the 2D one. A matter of taste, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, I just was thinking that no  one cancelled Okkam's razor yet :)

Comment: I don't see why you are letting $z = u^2 + v^2$ here, why couldn't you have done $z = (u^2 + v^2)^2$ to get a paraboloid?

Comment: @sizz -- because I'm more familiar with cones than with paraboloids.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(u+i v)^2 = (u^2-v^2) + i(2uv)$,
so you are looking at squaring the
complex values in the first and fourth quadrants in the complex plane.

This would double all the args of each point.
The points in the first quadrant
with args from $0$ to $\pi/2$ would map into the points
with args $0$ to $\pi$,
or the upper half plane.
The points in the fourth quadrant
with args from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$ would map into the points
with args $3\pi$ to $4\pi$,
or the lower half plane.

Together, these fill the whole plane,
so $h(A)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Note that the vertical axis $u=0$ does not belong to $A$. This has consequences for $h(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, for folks who like algebra better than geometry:

Given any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we can find find polar coordinates $r$ and $\theta$ such that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Then set 
$$ u = \sqrt r \cos\tfrac{1}{2}\theta  \quad ; \quad v = \sqrt r \sin\tfrac{1}{2}\theta  $$
It is easy to verify that $u^2 - v^2 = x$ and $2uv = y$.

So, for any given $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we can find $u,v$ such that $h(u,v)=(x,y)$. This shows that $h(A)$ is (almost) all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The only problems occur on the negative $x$-axis. If $y=0$, then  $uv=0$. But $u>0$, so this means $v=0$, so $x = u^2$, which must be positive. So, in fact, $h(A)$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the points $(x,0)$ where $x \le 0$.

Comment: You're right about excluded points. I completely forgot about those, since I took $u,v \in \mathbb R$. +1